# Compile-time constraint for complete pattern match

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, compiler-warnings

I'm looking for the warning number for incomplete pattern matches.  Anyone know what it is?

More fully, I want to make FSC.EXE return incomplete pattern matches as compile-time errors rather than warnings + run-time exceptions.  Does anyone know what the warning number for this is?  Specifically, this relates to compiled .fs / interactive FSI .fsx REPL interaction.

The warning:

```
Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For example, the value 'LaLaLa (_)' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).
```

How to customise:

see "--warnaserror[+|-] []"

ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233171(v=vs.140).aspx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

use `--warnaserror+:25`

To know which one it was I simply produced myself the warning using `let f (Some x) = x` which gaves me *warning FS0025: Incomplete pattern matches on this expression. For e
xample, the value 'None' may indicate a case not covered by the pattern(s).*

Comment: ty. This gets hidden when working via .fsx/FSI.  note: for others reading this, put this in the "Other Flags" area of Build options.

Answer (score 1):

In a .Net Standard F# project you can also achieve this by adding an element to your fsproj file like so:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
<WarningsAsErrors>FS0025</WarningsAsErrors>
</PropertyGroup>
```