# F# code attribute to treat "incomplete pattern match" as an error

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I'm wondering if there exists a code feature (not a compiler feature) in F# for making an incomplete pattern match come up as an error, not a warning.

I need this to be able to be on a case-by-case basis. i.e., in some places in the code, I would like an incomplete pattern match to be a warning, and in other places in the same assembly I'd like it to be an error. So it is not sufficient to set a compiler flag to treat *all* the incomplete pattern match warnings as errors, as [Compile-time constraint for complete pattern match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538390/compile-time-constraint-for-complete-pattern-match) suggests.

This would look perhaps something like

```
type MyUnion = First | Second

let foo x =
  match x with
  | First -> "hello"
  // raises a compile-time warning

let bar x =
  [<AssertCompleteMatch>]
  match x with
  | First -> "hello"
  // raises a compile-time error
```

Or perhaps that attribute would be applied to the type to make sure all pattern matches with that specific type are complete.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail the reasoning behind this? Generally, you don't want to have incomplete pattern matches ever. If you find yourself doing that very often, chances are that you've modeled your domain incorrectly.

Comment: My recommendation would be to turn on the flag and then fix all the places that have incomplete matches

Comment: Not sure what you'd expect such a "code feature" to look like. If something works at compile time, it *is* a compiler feature.

Answer (score 6):

You can have warning 25 be treated as an error, and then use

```
#nowarn "0025"
```

in files where you want to explicitly ignore it.  But disabling the warning is file-scope, rather than match-scope.  That's the best you can do, I think.